# How to add a counter to a recurring dataset in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table which has a recurring field. I need a function to count and say which recurrence is in nth line. i.e.;

If the table is as follows;

```
ID  NAME  CLASS
---------------
 1  Tom    a
 2  Dick   b
 3  Harry  c  
 4  Marry  b
 5  Bob    c
 6  Mat    c
 7  Mandi  a
```

A function like `COUNT(class)` can count how many times each class value has been occurred. But I need a function to output a result like follows;

```
ID  NAME  CLASS (I_NEED) COUNT
--------------------------------
 1  Tom     a      1       2
 2  Dick    b      1       2
 3  Harry   c      1       3
 4  Marry   b      2       2
 5  Bob     c      2       3
 6  Mat     c      3       3
 7  Mandi   a      2       2
```

I am using SQL Server 2010R2

Any ideas will come in great help.. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2010R2** - not even "2010" ; we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 is in the works - so which one are you *really* using ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select id, 
       name, 
       class,
       row_number() over (partition by class order by id) as i_need,
       count(*) over (partition by class) as cnt
from the_table
order by id
```